# in countWord example, I apply foreach but it has cannot resolved symbol error

Tags: scala, foreach

here is example about countWords. (Scala)

```
[origin]
def countWords(text: String): mutable.Map[String, Int] = {
  val counts = mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]
  for (rawWord <- text.split("[ ,!.]+")) {
    val word = rawWord.toLowerCase
    val oldCount =
      if (counts.contains(word)) counts(word)
      else 0
    counts += (word -> (oldCount + 1))
  }
  return counts
}

[my code]
here is my code.
def countWords2(text: String):mutable.Map[String, Int] = {
  val counts = mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]s

  text.split("[ ,!.]").foreach(word =>
    val lowWord = word.toLowerCase()
    val oldCount = if (counts.contains(lowWord)) counts(lowWord) else 0
    counts += (lowWord -> (oldCount + 1))
  )

  return counts
}
```

I tried transfer "for()" sentence to "foreach" but I got "cannot resolved symbol" error message.
how to use foreach in this case?

Comment: what about that "s" in `mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]s`?

Comment: Given the multiple lines within the `foreach` code block, you would need to replace parentheses with curly braces (i.e. `{}`).

Comment: @Andronicus 
that is incorrect characters.
@Leo C 
It works!! You are genius! Thanks! 

`def countWords2(text: String):mutable.Map[String, Int] = {
      val counts = mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]

      text.split("[ ,!.]+").foreach(word => {
        val lowWord = word.toLowerCase()
        val oldCount = if (counts.contains(lowWord)) counts(lowWord) else 0
        counts += (lowWord -> (oldCount + 1))
      })

      return counts
    }`